# Excel VBA function returning an array

Tags: vba, excel

Can you create an Excel VBA function that returns an array in the same manner as LINEST does, for example? I would to create one that, given a supplier code, returns a list of products for that supplier from a product-supplier table.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 21):

ok, here I have a function datamapping that returns an array of multiple 'columns', so you can shrink this down just to one.
Doesn't really matter how the array gets populated, particularly

```
Function dataMapping(inMapSheet As String) As String()

   Dim mapping() As String

   Dim lastMapRowNum As Integer

   lastMapRowNum = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(inMapSheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

   ReDim mapping(lastMapRowNum, 3) As String
   For i = 1 To lastMapRowNum
      If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(inMapSheet).Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
         mapping(i, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(inMapSheet).Cells(i, 1).Value
         mapping(i, 2) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(inMapSheet).Cells(i, 2).Value
         mapping(i, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(inMapSheet).Cells(i, 3).Value
      End If
   Next i

   dataMapping = mapping

End Function




Sub mysub()

   Dim myMapping() As String
   Dim m As Integer

   myMapping = dataMapping(inDataMap)

   For m = 1 To UBound(myMapping)

     ' do some stuff

   Next m   

end sub
```

Answer (score 8):

I think `Collection` might be what you are looking for.

Example:

```
Private Function getProducts(ByVal supplier As String) As Collection
    Dim getProducts_ As New Collection

    If supplier = "ACME" Then
        getProducts_.Add ("Anvil")
        getProducts_.Add ("Earthquake Pills")
        getProducts_.Add ("Dehydrated Boulders")
        getProducts_.Add ("Disintegrating Pistol")
    End If

    Set getProducts = getProducts_
    Set getProducts_ = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub fillProducts()
    Dim products As Collection
    Set products = getProducts("ACME")
    For i = 1 To products.Count
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = products(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Here is a pretty simple solution to the Problem: Populating a ComboBox for Products whenever the ComboBox for Suppliers changes it's value with as little vba as possible.

```
Public Function getProducts(ByVal supplier As String) As Collection
    Dim getProducts_ As New Collection
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim colProduct As Integer
    Dim colSupplier As Integer
    colProduct = 1
    colSupplier = 2

    numRows = Sheets(1).Cells(1, colProduct).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    For Each Row In Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(1, colProduct), Sheets(1).Cells(numRows, colSupplier)).Rows
        If supplier = Row.Cells(1, colSupplier) Then
            getProducts_.Add (Row.Cells(1, colProduct))
        End If
    Next Row

    Set getProducts = getProducts_
    Set getProducts_ = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub comboSupplier_Change()
    comboProducts.Clear
    For Each Product In getProducts(comboSupplier)
        comboProducts.AddItem (Product)
    Next Product
End Sub
```

Notes: I named the ComboBox for Suppliers comboSupplier and the one for Products comboProducts.

Comment: Like this?

Function FoundProds(SuppKey As Variant) As Variant

Dim ProdCell As Range
Dim SuppCell As Range
Dim Results(50)
Dim ResultCount As Integer
Dim ProdCol, SuppCol As Integer

ProdCol = 1 'Product Code in this column'
SuppCol = 2 'Supplier Codes are in this column'

ResultCount = 1
For Each ProdCell In Range(Cells(1, ProdCol), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ProdCol))
        If SuppKey = SuppCell.Value Then
            Results(ResultCount) = Cells(ProdCell.Row, ProdCol).Value
            ResultCount = ResultCount + 1
       End If
 Next
 FoundLocations = Results
End Function

Comment: I forgot to ask: You want to return the array to another VBA function right? or do you want to use the function directly in your worksheet as a custom function?

Comment: I'd like to use the function directly in the worksheet
I'm trying to let the user choose a supplier from a combo box, which will then populate a second combo box with that supplier's products, for a second choice. Sorry about the messy lump of code in my comment above!

Comment: Are we talking about a control or a list created through an named range inserted to validation criteria? 
If it's a control you just need to put a sub in the SupplierCombobox_Change event and if it's a validation rule I believe we need to work with a named range

Comment: It's a control. Though I am trying to avoid too much VBA as I will have to present this spreadsheet to some less IT literate people, so I would prefer not bury things in events and sich-like.... They might cope with a user-defined function.